# Windows 2008 R2 - BlueTooth support?

Tags: hardware, windows-server-2008-r2, bluetooth

Does Windows 2008 R2 have BlueTooth support? I know with some persuasion you could get 2008 to support it, but it was always ropey.

I'm going to use it as a development OS, but have BT keyboard and mouse - which work perfectly in the 7 RC...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know it doesn't. Bluetooth technology is aimed at the consumer end, not the "enterprise" end.

You could install Server 2008 R2 as a VM instead, then it wouldn't matter. You'd also be able to take and revert snapshot of your server, which would likely be quite useful for a dev environment.

Comment: Well, looks like I'm stuck on Win7 for the time being. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

If you google about a bit it seems that the frig to get it working on 2008 isn't working in the latest release of R2 - doesn't mean it won't when it's released but not just yet.

Answer (score 1):

You might check:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsserver2008r2networking/thread/1ea7b245-684e-4fd0-8784-44fa08ce3ebd

Answer (score 1):

Workaround? here..

I have two BT dongles, one Motorola and one Surecom. The Moto never worked, even trying to modify the drivers... and this Surecome (and no other PN or SN) worked like a charm with... TOSHIBA's drivers, v. 7.00.10, for XP/Vista/7 x64, which I have download from [here](http://aps2.toshiba-tro.de/Bluetooth/?page=download) 
The installation requires you to reboot your server and after the restart you have a 100% BT enabled server.

Cristian

Answer (score 0):

You might have to modify drivers, like in 2008.
http://www.gilkirkpatrick.com/Blog/post/Installing-the-Microsoft-Bluetooth-Stack-on-Windows-Server-2008.aspx